# How to check if a Cassandra table exists

Tags: cassandra, cql

Is there an easy way to check if table (column family) is defined in Cassandra using CQL (or API perhaps, using com.datastax.driver)?

Right now I am leaning towards executing `SELECT 1 FROM table` and checking for exception but maybe there is a better way?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As of 1.1 you should be able to query the `system` keyspace, `schema_columnfamilies` column family.  If you know which keyspace you want to check, this CQL should list all column families in a keyspace:

```
SELECT columnfamily_name
FROM schema_columnfamilies WHERE keyspace_name='myKeyspaceName';
```

The report describing this functionality is here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-2477

Although, they do note that some of the system column names have changed between 1.1 and 1.2.  So you might have to mess around with it a little to get your desired results.

**Edit 20160523 - Cassandra 3.x Update:**

Note that for Cassandra 3.0 and up, you'll need to make a few adjustments to the above query:

```
SELECT table_name 
FROM system_schema.tables WHERE keyspace_name='myKeyspaceName';
```

Comment: It works with CQL 3 but not with CQL 1 or 2:
SELECT columnfamily_name FROM System.schema_columnfamilies WHERE keyspace_name='myKeyspaceName';

Comment: If someone checks if a table exists, and if not then create it, then this method is not thread safe. If multiple threads/client perform this kind of action concurrently, select may return no result, but CREATE statement may already fail. In such case it's better to go with exception based solution.

Comment: it will not work with Datastax v3.0 driver. Use KeyspaceMetadata/TableMetadata for that

Comment: @Aaron is there any way (by quering system tables) to know the existence of a table BY NOT SPECIFYING KEYSPACE NAME ?

Comment: @Laxmikant Yes, if you know the table name, you can try: `SELECT * FROM system_schema.tables WHERE table_name='testmap' ALLOW FILTERING;`  As the `system_schema` keyspace uses `LocalStrategy`, it will not be nearly as inefficient as using `ALLOW FILTERING` on a regular table.

Answer (score 23):

The Java driver (since you mentioned it in your question) also maintains a local representation of the schema.

Driver 3.x and below:

```java
KeyspaceMetadata ks = cluster.getMetadata().getKeyspace("myKeyspace");
TableMetadata table = ks.getTable("myTable");
boolean tableExists = (table != null);
```

Driver 4.x and above:

```java
Metadata metadata = session.getMetadata();
boolean tableExists =
  metadata.getKeyspace("myKeyspace")
    .flatMap(ks -> ks.getTable("myTable"))
    .isPresent();
```

Comment: Good answer!  I didn't even *think* about using `TableMetadata` for that.

Comment: Perfect! That way you can even get easy access to the column definitions as well.

Comment: Works great with the DataStax driver v3, thanks Olivier!

Comment: My problem with this and the C++ driver is the fact that in my case it transfers 250Kb of data each time. My current implementation gets that meta data once on startup, which improves the speed much, but the data is in a separate service (I have a form of proxy to access Cassandra.) So I think this is the best way (as in cleanest), it's just that it's really slow.

Comment: With driver v4 an extra `.get()` is needed to unwrap the `Optional<KeyspaceMetadata>`, but other than that it still works.

Answer (score 7):

I just needed to manually check for the existence of a table using cqlsh.
Possibly useful general info.

```
describe keyspace_name.table_name
```

If it doesn't exist you'll get 'table_name' not found in keyspace 'keyspace'
If it does exist you'll get a description of the table.

Answer (score 0):

For the .NET driver `CassandraCSharpDriver` version 3.17.1 the following code creates a table if it doesn't exist yet:

```cs
var ks = _cassandraSession.Cluster.Metadata.GetKeyspace(keyspaceName);
var tableNames = ks.GetTablesNames();
if(!tableNames.Contains(tableName.ToLowerInvariant()))
{
   var stmt = new SimpleStatement($"CREATE TABLE {tableName} (id text PRIMARY KEY, name text, price decimal, volume int, time timestamp)");
   _cassandraSession.Execute(stmt);
}
```

You will need to adapt the list of table columns to your needs. This can also be awaited by using `await _cassandraSession.ExecuteAsync(stmt).ConfigureAwait(false)` in an async method.

Also, I want to mention that I'm using Cassandra version 4.0.1.